# convert one string type to another string type

Tags: go

I have two string types. I'm string to convert one string to another string type. This doesn't work and fails on the nextT = nextS assignment. Why? They both have an underlying string type. Thanks.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type TFirstType string
type TSecondType string

func main() {
    var firstT TFirstType 
    firstT = "asdf"

    var secondT = fmt.Sprintf("%s", firstT )

    nextS := secondT 
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(nextS))

    var nextT TSecondType 
    nextT = nextS
}

func (c TFirstType ) String() string {
    return string(c)
}
```

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/DwEY6hWacVA

Comment: If you want to convert from one type to another, use a [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions).

Comment: Type conversions are [covered in the Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/basics/13). Please take the entire tour, it covers all the language basics and will answer a lot of basic syntax questions.

Answer (score -1):

This wasn't obvious to, and I'm going to have to read a lot more to figure it out.JimB, Adrian, and Abu each helped. This worked...

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type TFirstType string
type TSecondType string

func main() {
    var firstT TFirstType 
    firstT = "asdf"

    var secondT = fmt.Sprintf("%s", firstT )

    nextS := secondT 
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(nextS))

    var nextT TSecondType 
    nextT = TSecondType(nextS)
    fmt.Println(nextT)
}

func (c TFirstType ) String() string {
    return string(c)
}
```